# localstack status services command is giving a JSON error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, localstack

getting a frustrating issue when running 'status services' against a running localstack, which appears to have started without error.

Most of the awslocal commands I attempt to run against localstack seem to work ok, so I am confused as to why 'localstack status services' fails

Error is below:

```
$  localstack status services
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/localstack/1.3.1/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/localstack", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/localstack", line 19, in main
    main.main()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/localstack/1.3.1/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/localstack/cli/main.py", line 11, in main
    cli()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/localstack/1.3.1/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/localstack/cli/plugin.py", line 15, in __call__
    self.group(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/localstack/1.3.1/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/localstack/1.3.1/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/localstack/1.3.1/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/localstack/1.3.1/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/localstack/1.3.1/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/localstack/1.3.1/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/localstack/1.3.1/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/localstack/cli/localstack.py", line 94, in cmd_status_services
    doc = health.json()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/localstack/1.3.1/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Hoping somebody has seen this before!

Edited this to reply to @thrau as the comment is too long...

```
$ curl localhost:4566/health
{"services": {"apigateway": "running", "cloudformation": "running", "cloudwatch": "running", "dynamodb": "running", "dynamodbstreams": "running", "ec2": "running", "es": "running", "firehose": "running", "iam": "running", "sts": "running", "kinesis": "running", "kms": "running", "lambda": "running", "logs": "running", "redshift": "running", "route53": "running", "s3": "running", "secretsmanager": "running", "ses": "running", "sns": "running", "sqs": "running", "ssm": "running", "events": "running", "stepfunctions": "running", "swf": "running", "resourcegroupstaggingapi": "running", "resource-groups": "running", "support": "running", "acm": "running"}, "features": {"persistence": "disabled", "initScripts": "initialized"}}
```

Comment: what does `curl localhost:4566/health` give you?

Comment: Added the response to my original post above. ^^

Comment: We have made a new release now. Can you update the CLI and try once again?